# how to get all set of results from google custom search api in REST mode i,e. through url?

Tags: google-custom-search

in google custom search REST, when i set start parameter to value more than 100 its not returning results i,e. start=101 its returning 400 status.

here is request to custom search  :

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDKVKBFRcdMnpmEtYNIJSE4kPw22O3yIpY&cx=004627592641946060093:sk0jmzk2vzc&q="+query+"&start=101"

the totalResults is 300 but it is not returning results for this request